# How to make an app developed in windows 8 x64 work on windows xp x86

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I recently developed an appin C#, it works perfect as expected in my PC but the app is to be installed in 32 bit PC with windows xp installed in it.. I've set the application target as .NET 3.5 wich should probably work in windows xp.. 
but i get an error.. "could not load assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic.powerpacks.VS version=10.0.0"

What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure it's also targeting x86 when you compile?

Comment: actually platform selection tab is disabled.. why that?

Comment: okay it was showing it for any PC, now I changed the things to x86

Comment: It works in windows xp sp3 but not in sp2. Probably, needs installation of .NET framework 3.5?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Alternatively, if you aren't using any of the 3.5 framework capabilities, downgrade to 3.0

Comment: downgrading it to 3.0 kills my mongocsharpdriver. I think i should leave it as 3.5

Comment: Yeah that's probably the best choice then.